# Extract title from bibtex

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, bibtex, org-ref

I want to extract the title of a bibtex entry by using a convenient org-ref function. Is there a way? How?

Im using org-ref with org-mode in spacemacs.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic function to look up the entry and title based on the citation at point (bibtex-completion is a dependency of org-ref):

```
(defun my/print-reference-title ()
  "Print the title to the reference at point in the minibuffer."
  (interactive)
  (message
   (assoc-default "title"
                  (bibtex-completion-get-entry
                   (org-ref-get-bibtex-key-under-cursor)))))
```